# how to read input of shell-script in docker container creating in detach mode

Tags: docker

```
docker run -d --name test -e Env=prod testimage
```

logs of container:

```
docker logs test
```

output:

```
Enter Environment Name local, prod or test:

Environment is not found
```

How to pass script input in detach mode?

Comment: What is the code running in there? Read and understand the code, then maybe the way to skip that interaction becomes obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The right mode are the environment variables which you used, by I see an error in your command line:

```bash
docker run -d --name test-e Env=prod testimage
```

Between `-name test` and `-e Env=prod` you missed a space:

```bash
docker run -d --name test -e Env=prod testimage
```

Comment: I used this also docker run -d --name test -e Env=prod testimage but not worked for me

Comment: You also need to modify your script to read the environment variable and not try to read from the container's stdin.